# Using proxy with pnp-auth in Node.js

Tags: pnp, nodejs

**Question :** 
Using `pnp-aut` and `node-sp-auth-config`, how can I specify the use of a proxy

**Context :**
Connect from within a `Node.js` app running on a server 'A' connecting to SharePoint on premise 'S'

given that I use this:

```
import { bootstrap } from 'pnp-auth';  
import { AuthConfig } from'node-sp-auth-config');
```

-> I have this working !

**BUT**:

Now I need the same `Node.js` app but running on a server 'B' connecting to the same SharePoint farm 'S'
**WITH** the requirement that to go from 'B' to 'S' I need to go through a corporate proxy.

Answer (score 0):

`pnp-auth` uses request module under the hood. `request` module, in turn, read info about proxy from env variables (and from configuration). Since currently it's not possible to change request configuration via `pnp-auth`, you can set env variables:

```
set https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888 
set http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Comment: Should I do that in a specific way ?  
I tried this in the app :  
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";   etc..

But that does not do the trick

Comment: `process.env` should work

Comment: I get a connection time-out error which specifies the IP of the SP server .... 
My admins tell me that is because I'm not going thru the proxy